# Best possible way to logout from rest client (time based)

Tags: java, android, rest

im currently working on a little user control for my app. My problem is, that i have no clue, how i can enforce a logout. I got a rdy method to logout on my rest server, all i need is some timer to enforce it, since android would not close the app if u press the home button (at least android wont let you override this button and handle the closing manually as far as i found out).

My login/logout works with a session id which is being saved in the database. Thats why i need it to be deleted after some time of inactivity.

Now i wonder if it is possible on the client side to somehow get the idle time, enforce logout and close app (even if app is not active on the screen)
or
handle this server side with a thread for every currently active session that does the logout after some time. (problem here: i have no idea where the main method from rest is running and how to even start/access threads then).

Thanks in advance for any answer, i rly appreciate any help here :)

Comment: store timestamp with your session id and check it when activity resumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service for your app which is started when the app is paused.
In the service you can implement a countdown which starts when the service is started, if the countdown runs out the service can fire your logout request.